# Insert more than 32000 characters in Oracle XML Type Column

Tags: xml, oracle, oracle11g, xmltype

I am using XML type Column on Oracle Db for one of my projects. 
After nitial use we realized that we can't insert more than 4000 Characters using the standard insert query.

With some browsing, I found a PL/SQL code which can be used.

```
  declare 
  x CLOB;

  BEGIN
  x:='long long... xml statement';
  insert into (xmlCol) values (xmltype(x));
  END;*
```

I am able to now insert over 4k characters to a maximum of 32772 characters.

Is there any way to remove the max character limitation, as our XMLs can have very large size.
Or, can we extend the character limit much higher using some other code block.

I am using  Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: The [duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20613348/working-with-very-large-text-data-and-clob-column) I closed this against is only talking about CLOBs, but that is what you need; build up your `x` as a CLOB in chunks of up to 32k, just as [that answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20614279/266304) builds `c1`; then your insert can still do `xmltype(x)`.

Comment: Thanks. This really helps.

Comment: If your XML is actually coming from a file and you're copying and pasting it in, you'll have to break it up manually; but if it is in a file and you can put that on the server, [loading directly from the file](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17299257/266304) would be easier.

Comment: You are right that loading from file is easier. But, we are generating the XMLs as part of the code so will have to go with breaking the XML into multiple strings and then append to CLOB. We are using webMethods for this work, so I can't directly run the statements and instead will have to wrap the logic in a stored procedure and call the SP for inserting.

Comment: @Adhiraj Can you provide the solution which you solved using webMethods?